# What's the best choice to develop an offline version of a struts webapplication?

Tags: struts, jetty, executable, war, rcp

We have a web application developed with struts 1 running on tomcat server. Now our clients want an offline version of it running only under windows.

I'd like to collect some advices from you: what's the best way to have this offline version? develop a new rich client from scratch?(RCP eclipse, RCP netbean, etc?) or try to generate a executable war with embedded jetty sever and embedded db like hsql?

thanks in advance.

Comment: As currently stated your question makes no sense. Please rephrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this done successfully as you mention, using and embedded instance of jetty, coupled with and embedded db.  Side benefit is it improves your development/testing environment as well since you can start up the whole thing in a unit test in your IDE and debug away :)

cheers